Update SVG Quadratic Bezier curve or Cubic curve to dragging the point on the path
Im tying to achieve dragging the point should always stay on the path should update the command Q or C or S to update the curve through the point, this draggable point should not be a control point, it should pull the curve with it.
Here image shows (15,5) pointer act as control pointer. but I want this draggable circle to stay on the path and when user drags it should pull the curve with it.
currently I am using x and y position of the draggable pointer with Q command.
const d = `M10,0 Q ${draggable.x} ${draggable.y} 400 390`;


Expected behavior is like this below in image, Draggable pointer should stick on top the path always and it should update the Q command or any Bezier command with its x and y.


Quadratic Béziers
You can calculate the coordinates of the drag handle based on the De Casteljau equation for quadratic curves
function getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  };
}

We can kind of reverse this process by solving the equation for a modified control point based on the coordinates of this moved drag handle – assuming the drag handle coordinates stay at t=0.5:
function quadraticControlPointAtT(p0, ptMid, p, t = 0.5) {
    let t1 = 1 - t;
    let cp1x = (ptMid.x - t1 * t1 * p0.x - t * t * p.x) / (2 * t1 * t);
    let cp1y = (ptMid.y - t1 * t1 * p0.y - t * t * p.y) / (2 * t1 * t);
    return { x: cp1x, y: cp1y };
}



//initial quadratic command points
let p0 = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}; // M starting point
let cp1 = {
  x: 100,
  y: 0
}; // quadratic bezier control point
let p = {
  x: 100,
  y: 100
}; // final on-path point

// align drag handle
let ptDrag = document.getElementById("ptDrag");

// calculate point a t=0.5 based on De Calejau equation
let ptMid = getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1, p, 0.5);
ptDrag.setAttribute("cx", ptMid.x);
ptDrag.setAttribute("cy", ptMid.y);

function getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  };
}

function quadraticControlPointAtT(p0, ptMid, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  let cp1x = (ptMid.x - t1 * t1 * p0.x - t * t * p.x) / (2 * t1 * t);
  let cp1y = (ptMid.y - t1 * t1 * p0.y - t * t * p.y) / (2 * t1 * t);
  return {
    x: cp1x,
    y: cp1y
  };
}

function updateQuadraticBezier(ptDrag) {
  let cp1_2 = quadraticControlPointAtT(p0, ptDrag, p, 0.5);
  let d = `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} Q ${cp1_2.x} ${cp1_2.y} ${p.x} ${p.y}`;
  path.setAttribute("d", d);
  newD.textContent = d;
}

/**
 * drag handler
 * based on Peter Collingridge's tutorial:
 * https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/
 */

svg.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
svg.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
svg.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
svg.addEventListener("mouseleave", endDrag);

let selectedElement = null;

function startDrag(evt) {
  if (evt.target.classList.contains("draggable")) {
    selectedElement = evt.target;
  }
}

function drag(evt) {
  if (selectedElement) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
    let ptDrag = {
      x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
      y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
    };
    selectedElement.setAttribute("cx", ptDrag.x);
    selectedElement.setAttribute("cy", ptDrag.y);

    // update bezier
    updateQuadraticBezier(ptDrag);
  }
}

function endDrag(evt) {
  selectedElement = null;
}
body {
  padding: 5em;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 1em
}

pre {
  background: #ccc
}
<code>
<pre id="newD">M0 0 Q 100 0 100 100</pre>
</code>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path id="path" d="M0 0 Q 100 0 100 100" stroke="#ccc" fill="none" />
  <circle class="draggable" opacity="1" id="ptDrag" cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red">
  </circle>
</svg>



Cubic Béziers
Unfortunately, we can't do the same trick since we have 2 variables – control point 1+2. We don't have a single solution to find the new coordinates for both control points. Vector editors often provide different methods to manipulate the curve on drag.
We also place the drag handle at t=0.5 based on the cubic equation helper (passing starting point, control point 1+2, final on-path point and the t value)
/**
 * calculate single points on cubic segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  let ptMid = {
    x:
      t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y:
      t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
  return ptMid;
}

One way to go would be this approach – also keeping the drag handle at t=0.5


function updateBezier(el, ptDrag, ptMid) {
  let pts = JSON.parse(el.dataset.pts).pts;
  let p0 = pts[0],
    cp1 = pts[1],
    cp2 = pts[pts.length - 2],
    p = pts[pts.length - 1];

  // just test if the new dragged point is still at t=0.5
  let ptM;
  let isQuadratic = pts.length === 3 ? true : false;

  if (isQuadratic) {
    cp1 = quadraticControlPointAtT(p0, ptDrag, p, 0.5);
    cp2 = cp1;
    d = `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} Q ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${p.x} ${p.y}`;
    ptM = getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1,p, 0.5);

  }

  //cubic
  else {
    cp1 = pts[1];
    cp2 = pts[pts.length - 2];
    
    // drag handle coordinates – inital t=0.5 x/y coordinates
    let xOff = ptDrag.x - ptMid.x;
    let yOff = ptDrag.y - ptMid.y;

    // Found this by accident - no idea at all why this works???
    let scale = 8 / 3;
    cp1.x += xOff * scale;
    cp2.y += yOff * scale;

    ptM = getPointAtCubicT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 0.5);
    d = `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y} ${p.x} ${p.y}`;
  }


  // point at t=0.5
  let t05 = el.parentNode.querySelector(".t05");
  t05.setAttribute("cx", ptM.x);
  t05.setAttribute("cy", ptM.y);


  let cp1_tangent = el.parentNode.querySelector(".t1");
  let cp2_tangent = el.parentNode.querySelector(".t2");

  // tangent handles
  cp1_tangent.setAttribute("x2", cp1.x);
  cp1_tangent.setAttribute("y2", cp1.y);
  cp2_tangent.setAttribute("x2", cp2.x);
  cp2_tangent.setAttribute("y2", cp2.y);


  let path = el.closest("svg").querySelector("path");
  path.setAttribute("d", d);
}

/**
 * calculate single points on quadratic segments
 */
function getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  return {
    x: t1 * t1 * p0.x + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.x + t ** 2 * p.x,
    y: t1 * t1 * p0.y + 2 * t1 * t * cp1.y + t ** 2 * p.y
  };
}

/**
 * get new control point at t=0.5 based on new mid point
 */
function quadraticControlPointAtT(p0, ptMid, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  let cp1x = (ptMid.x - t1 * t1 * p0.x - t * t * p.x) / (2 * t1 * t);
  let cp1y = (ptMid.y - t1 * t1 * p0.y - t * t * p.y) / (2 * t1 * t);
  return {
    x: cp1x,
    y: cp1y
  };
}

/**
 * calculate single points on cubic segments
 */
function getPointAtCubicT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, t = 0.5) {
  let t1 = 1 - t;
  let ptMid = {
    x:
      t1 ** 3 * p0.x +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.x +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.x +
      t ** 3 * p.x,
    y:
      t1 ** 3 * p0.y +
      3 * t1 ** 2 * t * cp1.y +
      3 * t1 * t ** 2 * cp2.y +
      t ** 3 * p.y
  };
  return ptMid;
}
body {
  padding: 5em;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: visible;
  margin: 1em;
  width: 25%;
}

pre {
  background: #ccc;
}

#markerRound {
  fill: #ccc;
}

.t {
  stroke: #ccc;
  marker-end: url(#markerRound);
}
<h3>Cubic/quadratic Bézier</h3>
<div id="svgWrp">
</div>

<!-- markers to show commands -->
<svg id="svgMarkers" style="width:0; height:0; position:absolute; z-index:-1;float:left;">
    <defs>
        <marker id="markerRound" overflow="visible" viewBox="0 0 10 10" refX="5" refY="5" markerUnits="strokeWidth"
          markerWidth="10" markerHeight="10" orient="auto-start-reverse">
          <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2.5" />
        </marker>
    </defs>
  </svg>



<script>
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {

    // create paths
    const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
    let paths = [{
        "pts": [{
          "x": 20,
          "y": 20
        }, {
          "x": 66.67,
          "y": 30
        }, {
          "x": 90,
          "y": 33.333
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        }]
      },
      {
        "pts": [{
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 0
        }, {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 100
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        }]
      },
      {
        "pts": [{
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        }, {
          "x": 0,
          "y": 50
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 50
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        }]
      },
      {
        "pts": [{
          "x": 0,
          "y": 0
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 0
        }, {
          "x": 100,
          "y": 100
        }]
      }
    ];


    paths.forEach(path => {
      let svg = document.createElementNS(ns, 'svg');
      let pathEl = document.createElementNS(ns, 'path');

      // get control points
      let pts = path.pts;
      let p0 = pts[0],
        cp1 = pts[1],
        cp2 = pts[pts.length - 2],
        p = pts[pts.length - 1];

      let isQuadratic = pts.length === 3;

      //cubic or quadratic
      let d = isQuadratic ?
        `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} Q ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${p.x} ${p.y}` :
        `M ${p0.x} ${p0.y} C ${cp1.x} ${cp1.y} ${cp2.x} ${cp2.y} ${p.x} ${p.y}`;

      pathEl.setAttribute('d', d);
      pathEl.setAttribute('fill', 'none');
      pathEl.setAttribute('stroke', '#999');

      svg.append(pathEl);
      svgWrp.append(svg);

      //adjust BBox
      let {
        x,
        y,
        width,
        height
      } = svg.getBBox();
      svg.setAttribute('viewBox', [x, y, width, height].join(' '));

      // add drag handles
      let dragHandle = `<circle class="draggable" opacity="1"  data-pts='${JSON.stringify(path)}' cx="0" cy="0" r="5" fill="red" />`;

      // t=0.5 indicator
      let t05 = `<circle class="t05" opacity="1" cx="0" cy="0" r="6" fill="green" />`;

      // control point visualizations
      let cp1_tangent = `<line class="t t1" x1="${p0.x}" y1="${p0.y}" x2="${cp1.x}" y2="${cp1.y}" stroke="#000"/>`;
      let cp2_tangent = `<line class="t t2" x1="${p.x}" y1="${p.y}" x2="${cp2.x}" y2="${cp2.y}" stroke="#000"/>`;

      let tangents = cp1_tangent + cp2_tangent;
      svg.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', t05 + dragHandle + tangents)
      addDrag(svg);

    })




    /**
     * drag handler
     * based on Peter Collingridge's tutorial:
     * https://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/tutorials/svg/interactive/dragging/
     */

    function addDrag(svg) {
      // align drag handle
      let ptDrag = svg.querySelector(".draggable");
      let t05 = svg.querySelector(".t05");

      let pts = JSON.parse(ptDrag.dataset.pts).pts
      let p0 = pts[0];
      let cp1 = pts[1]
      let cp2 = pts[pts.length - 2]
      let p = pts[pts.length - 1];

      // calculate point a t=0.5 based on De Casteljau equation
      let ptMid = pts.length === 3 ? getPointAtQuadraticT(p0, cp1, p, 0.5) : getPointAtCubicT(p0, cp1, cp2, p, 0.5)
      ptDrag.setAttribute("cx", ptMid.x);
      ptDrag.setAttribute("cy", ptMid.y);

      t05.setAttribute("cx", ptMid.x);
      t05.setAttribute("cy", ptMid.y);

      svg.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrag);
      svg.addEventListener("mousemove", drag);
      svg.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrag);
      svg.addEventListener("mouseleave", endDrag);
      let selectedElement = null;

      function startDrag(evt) {
        if (evt.target.classList.contains("draggable")) {
          selectedElement = evt.target;
        }
      }

      function drag(evt) {
        if (selectedElement) {
          evt.preventDefault();
          let CTM = svg.getScreenCTM();
          let ptDrag = {
            x: (evt.clientX - CTM.e) / CTM.a,
            y: (evt.clientY - CTM.f) / CTM.d
          };
          selectedElement.setAttribute("cx", ptDrag.x);
          selectedElement.setAttribute("cy", ptDrag.y);
          // update bezier
          updateBezier(selectedElement, ptDrag, ptMid);
        }
      }

      function endDrag(evt) {
        selectedElement = null;
      }
    }
  })
</script>



The new cubic control point coordinates are calculated like so:
// drag handle coordinates - inital t=0.5 coordinates
let xOff = ptDrag.x - ptMid.x;
let yOff = ptDrag.y - ptMid.y;

// ???
let scale = 8 / 3;
cp1.x += xOff * scale;
cp2.y += yOff * scale;

Disclaimer: I have no idea why the "magic constant"  of ~ 2.6667 or 8/3 does the trick – just accidentally found it by checking multiple values to find a pattern. Obviously, there is a mathematical explanation based on the aforementioned equations.
Full control?
As you can see from the cubic Bézier examples the on-path dragging concept has limitations (or it requires a some restraints). While it may provide a intuitive editing experience at first glance – moving the actual control points is the most versatile editing concept. Besides, making control points draggable also simplifies you app code base significantly as you only need to get the control point coordinates from the path data and can update these according to dragged coordinates.
